# AS3 parallax effect in Flash banner preventing Movieclip buttons from functioning

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm building a rich media Flash banner ad. I have 3 to 4 round MovieClip buttons that move around with an AS3 parallax effect. It looks like an EnterFrame loop creates the effect in AS3. But the individual Movieclip buttons won't function when I assign MouseEvent Click events. I want the parallax movement to stop and playhead advance to a specific label on main timeline when the MC's are clicked.
I'm sure this can be done but I lack the expertise. Here is the code:

```
//add an event listener to trigger every frame
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

//set a constant that marks the centre of the stage
//the stage is 600 x 400, so we halve that
const stageCentre:Point=new Point(180,300);

//set an easing constant
const ease:Number=0.2;

function onFrame(e:Event) {
//create a point to store the distances the mouse is from the centre
var mouseOffset:Vector3D=new Vector3D(stageCentre.x-mouseX,stageCentre.y-mouse Y, 0);

//move each background layer by a different percentage of offset
//the easing constant is used here to create smoother results

//foreground moves the most; 75% of the mouse offset
clip1_mc.x+=(stageCentre.x+mouseOffset.x*0.70 - clip1_mc.x)*ease;
clip1_mc.y+=(stageCentre.y+mouseOffset.y*0.50 - clip1_mc.y)*ease;

//mid-ground moves a medium amount; 50% of the mouse offset
clip2_mc.x+=(stageCentre.x+mouseOffset.x*1.00 - clip2_mc.x)*ease;
clip2_mc.y+=(stageCentre.y+mouseOffset.y*1.00 - clip2_mc.y)*ease;

//background moves the least; 25% of mouse offset
clip3_mc.x+=(stageCentre.x+mouseOffset.x*1.75 - clip3_mc.x)*ease;
clip3_mc.y+=(stageCentre.y+mouseOffset.y*1.00 - clip3_mc.y)*ease;
}


//Click on button to go to and Play "kelsey" label (this does NOT work)

clip1_mc.kelsey_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("kelsey");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the clip1_mc is on the top most layer, it is probably overlapped by other clips that are catching up the mouse click events.

If you have buttons in all layers you will need to disable mouse events for everything except the buttons. For example, if you have a "button" and a "background" in each movieclip and you want to only keep the buttons clickable, do something like this inside of that movieclip:

```
background.mouseEnabled = false;
background.mouseChildren = false;
```

This way the background will not listen for any mouse interactions

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but there are no backgrounds in the MCs. The MC consists of a solid color. There are 3 of them and they are on separate layers. The only elements in the Flash file are the 3 circles until I can get this

Answer (score 0):

add removeEventlistener when the mouse clicks the movieclip

```
clip1_mc.kelsey_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("kelsey");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance -- I tried that before and even though removing the Event Listener onFrame stops the parallax movement and all the circles stop moving upon clicking the clip1_mc, the gotoAndPlay part doesn't work. There must be some other code that is interfering with the code that simply wants to advance the playhead on the timeline. (?) Very frustrating!